# Custom post type's permalink adds the name of the post type before the post name

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

So I've create a custom post type which seem to work.

however the permalinks of the create posts has the name of the custom post type in-front of the post name.

I am getting addresses like:
`http://demoforhim2.e-ddl.com/movie_reviews/secondone/`

and trying to change that to : `http://demoforhim2.e-ddl.com/secondone/`

I've tried using rewrite with empty slug but it did not work.

Here is my custom post type

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_movie_review' );
function create_movie_review() {
register_post_type( 'movie_reviews',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Movie Reviews',
            'singular_name' => 'Movie Review',
            'add_new' => 'Add New',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New Movie Review',
            'edit' => 'Edit',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit Movie Review',
            'new_item' => 'New Movie Review',
            'view' => 'View',
            'view_item' => 'View Movie Review',
            'search_items' => 'Search Movie Reviews',
            'not_found' => 'No Movie Reviews found',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Movie Reviews found in Trash',
            'parent' => 'Parent Movie Review'
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'menu_position' => 15,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'thumbnail' ),
        'taxonomies' => array( '' ),
        'menu_icon' => plugins_url( 'images/16x16.png', __FILE__ ),
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => '', 'with_front' => FALSE) /*doesnt seem to work*/
    )
);
}
```

for some reason the above doesn't work properly.

Comment: yea but there should be a way to remove it. and a url example would be http://demoforhim2.e-ddl.com/movie_reviews/secondone/ I am trying to get rid of movie_reviews.

Comment: Set slug to false instead of ''. Source: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6832/how-do-you-remove-slug-altogether-from-custom-post-type

Comment: I don't know if that will work. Seems to have worked for the OP but not for others. Anyhow, I think wordpress.SE will have more on this in their archives than Stackoverflow will.

Comment: checked - using false does not work

Comment: What is your permalink structure?  Do you have it set to just /%postname%/  ?

Comment: Yea it is now set as domain.com//%postname%/

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => '/')
```

Output: example.com/headline/

Slug removed—no extra slashes.

Remember to flush permalinks (settings->permalinks)

Source: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-can-i-create-a-custom-post-type-with-empty-slug